# what is !Account.contact

Tags: visualforce

I wrote a simple visualforce code

```
  <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="contact" cellpadding="4" border="1">
     <apex:column >{!contact.name}</apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>
```

from pages developer guide.

there is a line which says

I dont understand what is {!Account.contacts}, as there is no field named contacts for Account.

I am relatively new to salesforce coding. can you help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not understanding what is meant by {!Account.Contact}](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78006/not-understanding-what-is-meant-by-account-contact)

Answer (score 4):

Contacts is standard related list of Contacts on Account object.

When an object A has relation to object B, this other object has list of related objects A.

If you open Account lookup on Contact object, you will see that Child Relationship Name is "Contacts".

In short, this is list off all contacts that relate to given account.

When you are using custom relation, you should add __r suffix to name of relation. "Addresses__r" in your case.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the quick turnaround. I understand your point however i created a custom object named Address having a lookup to Account, where child relationship name is "Addresses". However now when i am writing the same code<apex:page standardController="Account">  
  <apex:pageBlock title="Address">
      <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.Addresses}" var="contact" cellpadding="4" border="1">
        
      </apex:dataTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page> it gives me an error stating  "Error: Invalid field Addresses for SObject Account ", any ideas why i am getting this error?

Comment: I just updated my answer.